# regular expression on python picking only one-digit number

Tags: python, regex

I'd like that **only one-digit** number to be picked.
On windows `python`, using Japanese `unicode`, I've:

```
s = "17 1 27歳女1"
re.findall(r'[1-7]\b', s)
```

I need to match the second `1` and last `1` in `s` - not `17` initial `1`.
Desired output:

```
['1', '1']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the regex you're looking for:

```
(?<!\d)[1-7](?!\d)
```

Test:

```
import re
s="17 1 27歳女1"
re.findall(r'(?<!\d)[1-7](?!\d)', s)
```

Output:

```
['1', '1']
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `<`

Comment: `(?<![stuff])` stands for negative lookbehind. Making sure the character before selected is *not* a number.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a [negative-lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)  `(?<!\d)`. This will ignore matches where a digit is preceded by another one, i.e.:

```
import re

s = "17 1 27歳女1"
x = re.findall(r"(?<!\d)[1-7]\b", s)
print(x)
# ['1', '1']
```

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/06IMQa/2/)
[Python Demo](https://jdoodle.com/a/Q5W)

---

**Regex Explanation:**

[image]